# Back4app api key

Tags: security, back4app

Hello i'm developing an application with flutter and using Back4app as my hosting, learning the documentation i have noticed that the api key for connecting to the server are placed inside the code in a separated class and then we can call this function to connect:

```
var httpLink = HttpLink(
 uri: 'https://parseapi.back4app.com/graphql',
 headers: {
  'X-Parse-Application-Id' : kParseApplicationId,
  'X-Parse-Client-Key' : kParseClientKey,
  'X-Parse-Master-Key': kParseMasterKey,
  //'X-Parse-REST-API-Key' : kParseRestApiKey,
},
);
```

How much secure is this ? We are not encountering any risk if someone somehow reverse my code and grab these keys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make it secure, you can not use the Master Key in the client side as it gives access to whole data. You can protect your data using ACLs/CLPs. You can see more details at this link: https://www.back4app.com/docs/security/parse-security

Comment: thank you for your answer, probably is better to remove also this from documentation (as my suggestions) if not needed...